# Express and Backbone Routing with pushState

Tags: backbone.js, express

I am new to both of these technologies and am wondering how is the best way to configure my app. I want to have no hastags and just use pushState. Also from what I read its best to have a mix between rendering server side and client side but I am not sure how to set this up. I have figured out how to do it one or the other but not together.

As of right now here is where I am at:

Express routes

```
app.get('/', site.index);
app.get('/product/:id', wiki.show);
```

Again this works fine without using pushState but now how do I combine the two together?

Answer (score 1):

To create a hybrid client/server app, you want both the client and server to be able to render every view. When a user visits your site, the server render the view and sends the html to the user. At this point, the client-side app loads and any relative links should be intercepted and replaced with backbone navigation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function(e){
  href = $(this).prop('href')
  root = location.protocol+'//'+location.host+'/'
  if (root===href.slice(0,root.length)){
    e.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate(href.slice(root.length), true);
  }
});
```

This line of code, once the backbone app has started, will catch all anchor tags without a data-bypass attribute and fire route functions in your client application instead of sending requests for that page to the server. Add a data-bypass attribute to create a link that will not fire a route function.